# Matching the url based on the page the user is on

Tags: php

I'm trying to right a simple `if` statement to basically say that if the user is on page_A then `echo "i am on page A";` and if I'm on page_B then `echo "i am on the page B";` and I'm using the **PHP** function `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to check if they match what is in my string that is stored in the variable `$page_A` and `$page_B`.

my code is as follows:

```
<?php
    $page_A = "/test.co.za/voice/";
    $page_B = "/test.co.za/artistes/";
    $match = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if ( $page_A == $match ) {
        echo "i am on page A";
    }elseif ( $page_B == $match ) {
        echo "i am on the page B";
    }
?>
```

Where am i going wrong or is there another way i can achieve getting this to work?

Thanks team :)

Comment: So whats not working? `var_dump($match);` what do you get?

Comment: `var_dump($match);` is giving me the URL but i was just abit lost with my logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'voice')!==false){
  echo "i am on page A";
}elseif(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'artistes')!==false){
  echo "i am on the page B";
}
```

Comment: Perfect brother. You the man yo!! worked like a charm. @Alex i didn't really want to modify the .htaccess file but i will keep it in mind for future reference thanks a lot team.I still have to learn more about .htaccess files if i am going to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand how you are doing this, if you have 2 different pages you always know at which page you are.

If you are using htaccess to redirect the request to a unique file, you should do something like this: 
Add this line in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]*)\/?([0-9a-zA-Z-_]*)\/?([0-9a-zA-Z-_]*)\/?([0-9a-zA-Z-_]*)\/?$ index.php?p=$1&s=$2&d=$3&ID=$4&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Now, if you open for instances: http://test.co.za/voice/ this will be redirected to /index.php. 
At index.php you can read:

```
$page = $_REQUEST['p'];
if ($page == 'voice') { //do stuff }
```